# Windows 7 Task bar + Chrome tab Issue

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When you have say more then one file or something open or window (not tabs), the windows 7 task bar combines or stacks them on top of each other. Well my chrome started to do that with tabs. It looks like I have more then one chrome window open, but its just tabs all in one window. So when I click on the stacked chrome on my task bar it shows a preview of each tab and then goes to that tab. I would much rather have it be one chrome icon rather then stacked and then I can select my tab. The preview for the many  tabs I have open is annoying me. I know this has to be something I accidental turned on because it did not do this before nor does it do it on my other computers.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you change the process model that chrome uses?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, chrome has three process models it can use.  The first one is where all tabs runs in the same process, the second is where each tab runs in a separate process, the third is where tabs opened from within another tab share a process.  The process model came to mind given it might change how Windows is interpreting how many "windows" are open for the taskbar preview.  It might not apply though, since it seems like this should be a setting.  So the process model can change by use of command line argument to chrome.  Any chance you recently switched between stable/beta/dev branches?

Comment: Actually yes. I am on dev, but so are my other computers.

Comment: Did you recently switch to the dev branch by any chance?  Any recent changes in that branch that would provoke this change?

Comment: Well I dont see anything appended to the shortcut call.

Comment: I am running stable (4.1.249.1042 beta (42199)) and can confirm that the thumbnail for Chrome is simply the active tab.  If you are serious about figuring this out you could switch to stable, test, switch back and you would know its the dev branch that is causing this behavior.  If you did this, I don't know if there are any potential profile/settings problems switching between branches.

Comment: What is the best way to switch back? Do I just download and install?

Comment: Check my answer below.  If I were you I would downgrade to stable unless you absolutely need Dev features, otherwise if you like Dev branch, it seems the Compatibility Mode hack works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick web search pulls [this](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/03/19/google-chrome-beta-dev-channels-now-support-windows-7-taskbar-t/), dated a week or so ago.  It seems like the new beta and dev releases now have tabs showing up as separate thumbnails:

> Apart from other minor patches and
>   fixes users of both testing versions
>   on Windows 7 now see per-tab taskbar
>   thumbnail previews.

Further research indicates that while IE8 has the capability to turn this per-tab thumbnail off, Chrome will only disable it if Aero Peek is disabled.

There seems to be an awkward way to disable it, listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37957#c59), involving running Chrome in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Running it in compatibility seemed to fixed the issue, I even get the 1 window preview as well like normal. Thanks

Comment: Nice, glad it works.